# Loop to created multiple Context Menus

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I have a chunk of code:

```
        for (game in settings_object.games)
        {   
            chrome.contextMenus.create({
                "title": "Add thread("+request.thread+") to game: "+game,
                "contexts":["page"],
                "onclick": function () {addThreadToGame(game,request.thread)}
            });

        }
```

That generates a context menue like:

- Add thread (1234) to game: ID of Game One
- Add thread (1234) to game: ID of Game Two
- Add thread (1234) to game: ID of Game Three

and the intention is for when the user clicks on **"Add thread (1234) to game: ID of Game One"** then **addThreadToGame("ID of Game One", "1234")** get's executed... unfortunately it seems like addThreadToGame is always triggered as addThreadToGame **("ID of Game Three", "1234")** because the value being passed to the function is always the last value it has at run time not menu generation time... what am I missing?

Comment: This answer seems to have half of the answer I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567437/selection-and-site-search-in-chrome-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked out the answer:

> ```
>       for (game in settings_object.games)
>       {   
>           chrome.contextMenus.create({
>               "title": "Add thread("+request.thread+") to game: "+game,
>               "contexts":["page"],
>               "onclick": (function(element) {
>                       return function(info, tab) {
>                           addThreadToGame(element,request.thread)
>                       }
>                   })(game)
>
>           });
>       }
> ```

after adapting the code I found in [selection and site search in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567437/selection-and-site-search-in-chrome-extension)